# How to call a Component which name is passed as props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm new at React. Basically i want to call different components based on the string passed as props. I've component named Device that have as prop the name of a particular device and in Device i want to call another components which has as name the props. Something like this: `<DeviceName/>`

This is my code:
App.js

```
<Device name = {devName} />
```

Device.js

```
import DeviceMark from ./devices/DeviceMark
function DeviceName({devName}) {
    const DevName = devName;
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path = "/" exact><DevName /></Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Imagine that in this case DevName will replace DeviceMark

Comment: Is `devName` actually a string value representing the "name" of a component or is it a reference to a component?

Comment: If it has to be a string, you can use an object like `const comps = { "devName": <DevName /> }` to map each string to a component. You can also pass a Component as prop though.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I decided to create a function in which i pass the name (as string) of one of my component, and using  a switch case i return the tag of the component that i need

Answer (score 0):

When you really need to convert string component names to actual components while rendering, I can suggest following way

```
import DeviceMark from ./devices/DeviceMark

function DeviceName({devName}) {
    const mappingComponents = {
        foo: FooComponent,
        bar: BarComponent,
        deviceMark: DeviceMark
    };
    const ComponentToRender = mappingComponents[devName || 'foo'];
    
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path = "/" exact><ComponentToRender></ComponentToRender></Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

More details in official doc - https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement).  It allows to create React element from string (if it's a basic html tag) or from function (if it's a React component).

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const DeviceName = () => {
  return 'sub component'
}

const Device = ({subDev}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { React.createElement(subDev) }
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return <Device subDev={DeviceName} />
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

It's a little example. I have a main component `Device`. It accepts a sub-component via a prop and I pass sub-component to `createElement`. It does not matter if sub-component whether basic html tag or `React` component.

It's [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-wozniak-4bgci?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).